# Mapkit Searchbar Autocomplete Ios8

Tags: objective-c, autocomplete, ios8, mapkit, searchbar

I'm trying to implement an Autocomplete on a search bar on a map using Mapkit. I found this :
https://github.com/chenyuan/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete
Works and is totally perfect except that it uses UISearchDisplayViewController which has been deprecated in ios8 and replaced by UISearchViewController. Is there a way around it or a simpler way than the one mentioned above?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Please try this new repo: https://github.com/hkellaway/HNKGooglePlacesAutocomplete, which is being actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides a full autocomplete for the entire English language (and others) but if you want to implement your own autocomplete it's not too difficult, you simply need the range of words or phrases that you want to suggest and a way of ranking them in order of frequency used.

I've implemented a simple autocomplete in one of my projects that centers around a `PredictionString` class and an `AutopredictCoordinator` class.

The `PredictionString` has a `NSString` property and a `float` property which relates to the strings frequency of use by the user. The `AutopredictCoordinator` then holds an array of prediction strings and responds to requests for the most likely completion of any given string.

Comment: How can I use the apple provided autocomplete??

Comment: As standard with iOS 8+ when filling in a `uitextfield` or `uitextview` apple provides the ribbon above the keyboard with suggestions for the current word you're entering.